# How to use two datatables in Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports, dataset

I have a issue in Crystal Reports: I need to print a report where values come from three tables

1. Booking_detail
2. av_details
3. booking_food_details

So, for this I have used datatable which has all the fields necessary. The Crystal Report header section has `Booking_detail`'s values, the detail section `av_details` and `booking_food_details` side by side in two columns, and in the report footer section has data from `Booking_detail` again, for this I have query:

```
select 
    b.Booking_id, booked_by, Datetime, FP_no, Name, co_name,
    Booking_type, occupation, Nationality, Address, email_id,
    Pan_no, sitting_arrang, state, city, pin_code, 
    Booking_from, Booking_to, Venue_type, Type_of_function, 
    Food_Pickup_hour, Food_Pickup_min, Min_people, Cost_per_plate,
    Total, Av_item_total, Grant_amount, Advance, Due, Payment_mode,
    card_type, Card_no, av.av_item, av.av_rate, food.Food_menu 
from 
    Booking_details b, av_details av, booking_food_details food 
where 
    b.Booking_id = @Booking_id 
    and b.Booking_id = av.Booking_id 
    and b.Booking_id = food.Booking_id
```

Now the problem here is that  av_details and booking_food_details have different number of rows. Suppose:

- `booking_food_details` has a,b,c and
- `av_details` has d,e,f,g,h

so when I run it with data it shows 5 lines of entry and av_details rows repeats itself 5 times, like :

```
booking_food_details                   av_details
       d                                    a
       e                                    b
       f                                    c
       g                                    a
       h                                    b
```

Rather it should display:

```
booking_food_details                   av_details
       d                                    a
       e                                    b
       f                                    c
       g                                    
       h
```

So please help, and please try to least technical as not very efficient on C# yet.

**EDITED :**

I have also used subreport but of no use, I have used two subreports one for Food menu and other AVdetails, but food menu shows data but main report has no data even avdetails shows only header nothing else

Thanks

Comment: If you are still having issues, then please edit your original question and post some more details to further explain the problem.

Comment: @bluefeet thanks it made my question more clear, however what more info you need, I think I have given all the info required here, so can you be a bit more specific.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

If you have different datasets/tables use a subreport to display each set of data.

Comment: I even tried that but its not showing relevant data, can you tell me basics of using subreport.